# Can I get back to normal scroll-to-target behavior with asynchronous content?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm loading content on demand on a webpage I'm working on. For various reasons, I'm also using the default browser behavior of scrolling to the :target fragment. You know, you click on a link that looks like `#abc` and the browser scrolls to `id="abc"` in your page.

Except that's not exactly what happens when the content is made available asynchronously. According to my [test page](http://smith-li.com/test/targetbug), you have to click the link twice in order to have the the browser scroll to the asynchronously-added element or the CSS3 `:target` selector select it. So what I can do about it so that my users don't have to click twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback function to `.load`, which scrolls to the just-added element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   "use strict";
   $("a[href=#loadme]").click(function () {
       if ("testcomplete" in window && window.testcomplete) {
            return;
       }
       $("#loadhere").load("loadme.inc", function(){
            location.href = this.href;
            //Your method to scroll "for various reasons"
       });
       window.testcomplete = true;
       return true; //Prevent default behaviour, ie following the `href` target
   })
})
```